# How to arrange divs side by side automatically?

Tags: html, css, inline

I want to insert divs as event entries in a "div_outside". The event entry should take 100% of the width if there is no other entry next to it. If there is another entry next to it, they should both be the same size next to each other.

[image]

My current code looks like this, but doesnt work:

test.css:

```
.column_div{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 800px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: solid black;
}   

.new_event1{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.new_event2{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="column_div" id="column_div"></div>

    <script src="test.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
column_div = document.getElementById("column_div")

new_event1 = document.createElement("div")
new_event1.classList.add("new_event1");

column_div.appendChild(new_event1)

new_event2 = document.createElement("div")
new_event2.classList.add("new_event2");

column_div.appendChild(new_event2)
```

How i can do that with html and css?

Comment: always share code instead of pictures and put it in a snippet and make sure it runs properly. and before you ask, please learn and practice.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the `display: flex` CSS attribute is what you're looking for.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .div_outside {
        border: 2px solid black;
        display: flex;
      }
      .div_outside > div {
        border: 2px solid red;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: blue;
        height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div_outside">
      <div>Div 1</div>
      <div>Div 2</div>
      <div>Div 3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dominik Borchert, but the problem is, if 2 divs are not directly next to each other in the outside_div but offset in height, they still have only 50% width. But then they should be 100% wide.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't actually explain clearly what exactly you want but I think what you mean is that you want divs to be in a row with equal space. and if there is only one div, it should take 100% width. is that it? check the code and let me know if this is what you want or not.

for that, you need to make the **parent** `display: flex:` with `flex-direction: row:` and you don't need to use `float`.

```js
column_div = document.getElementById("column_div")

new_event1 = document.createElement("div")
new_event1.classList.add("new_event1");

column_div.appendChild(new_event1)

new_event2 = document.createElement("div")
new_event2.classList.add("new_event2");

column_div.appendChild(new_event2)


// new_event3 = document.createElement("div")
// new_event3.classList.add("new_event3");

// column_div.appendChild(new_event3)
```

```css
.column_div{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: solid black;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}   

.new_event1{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.new_event2{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
/* 
.new_event3{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
} */
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="column_div" id="column_div"></div>

    
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Willpower-7, but the problem with your code still exists. If the red div has the attribute top=300px, then both divs should get 100% width, because they are no longer at the same height. But at your code bothe divs still have the width of 50%.